# What does boost::thread do if it fails to create the thread?

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading

What does boost::thread do if it fails to create the thread?

The winAPI returns a NULL (I guess posix does something similar) but as thread is an object how do I test to see if the thread was created?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/thread.html), it throws a `boost::thread_resource_error` if the thread creation fails.

I guess you cannot create an invalid `boost::thread` object: if something goes wrong, the constructor throws thus preventing the object creation.

Comment: Thanks, I did look in the documentation, don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 8):

[Throws: `boost::thread_resource_error` if an error occurs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.callable_constructor)

Comment: Thanks, given the answer to ereOn as he answered moments before you